# What kind of average could give a Lorentz invariant energy-momentum tensor?

Tags: special-relativity, vacuum, lorentz-symmetry, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, cosmological-constant

The electromagnetic (EM) radiation energy-momentum tensor is of the following shape, in the case of *incoherent superposition of EM plane waves* (I'm using $c = 1$ to simplify things, and metric signature $\eta = (1, -1, -1, -1)$):
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
T_{ab} =\int k_a \, k_b \, f(\omega) \, d^3 k,
\end{equation}
where $k^a$ is a *ligth-like* 4-vector (so $k_a \, k^a = 0$).  The energy-momentum of EM radiation should have a null trace: $\eta^{ab} \, T_{ab} = 0$.  Expression (1) satisfy this constraint, and cannot gives something like a Lorentz invariant energy-momentum (which implies a *negative* pressure: $p = -\, \rho$):
\begin{equation}\tag{2}
T_{ab}^{\text{vac}} = \rho \, \eta_{ab}.
\end{equation}
Obviously, this expression cannot have a $0$ trace: $\eta^{ab} \, T_{ab}^{\text{vac}} = 4 \rho \ne 0$.  So (2) cannot describe an incoherent superposition of random radiation.

The function $f(\omega)$ is arbitrary under integral (1), but is defined in the special frame for which radiation is isotropic.  It's easy to verify that the pressure of the radiation is $p = \smash{\frac{1}{3}} \, \rho$, in the rest frame of the incoherent radiation:
\begin{align}
\rho \equiv T_{00} &= \int \omega^2 \, f(\omega) \, d^3 k = 4 \pi \int \omega^4 \, f(\omega) \, d\omega. \tag{3} \\[12pt]
T_{0 i} &= \int \omega^2 \, n_i \, f(\omega) \, d^3 k = 0. \qquad \text{(from isotropy in the rest frame)} \tag{4} \\[12pt]
T_{ij} &= \int \omega^2 \, n_i \, n_j \, f(\omega) \, d^3 k = \int \omega^4 \big( \frac{4 \pi}{3} \, \delta_{ij} \big) \, f(\omega) \, d\omega \equiv \frac{1}{3} \, \rho \, \delta_{ij}. \tag{5}
\end{align}
Expression (5): $\smash{T_{ij} = \frac{1}{3} \, \rho \, \delta_{ij}}$, implies that the radiation pressure is $\smash{p = \frac{1}{3} \, \rho}$, as it should for random radiation, and that the full energy-momentum of incoherent EM radiation cannot be Lorentz invariant (i.e $T_{ab}^{\text{rad}} \ne \rho \, \eta_{ab}$).

Using massive non-interacting particles instead of EM radiation doesn't help, since expression (with $p_a \, p^a = m^2$)
\begin{equation}\tag{6}
T_{ab} =\int p_a \, p_b \, f(E) \, d^3 p
\end{equation}
necessarily gives a positive pressure.  Similar calculations as (3)-(5) give
\begin{align}
\rho = 4 \pi \int \sqrt{E^2 - m^2} \, f(E) \, E^3 \, dE &\equiv \int g(E) \, dE, \tag{7} \\[12pt]
p = 4 \pi \int \frac{E^2 - m^2}{3 E^2} \sqrt{E^2 - m^2} \, f(E) \, E^3 \, dE &\equiv \int \frac{E^2 - m^2}{3 E^2} \, g(E) \, dE. \tag{8}
\end{align}
Adding energy-momentum of radiation and particles still give a positive total pressure (which makes sense, physically).

> So my question is how could we modify the expressions (1) and (6) to get (2)?  Using a *negative* function $f$ is weird!  Is there any other possibility?  Do I need to add some ***attractive interaction*** into this picture, to get a *negative pressure* (fluid in *tension*)?  If so, what would be a simple model of particles in interaction that modifies (6) and gives a negative pressure?

---

**Remark:**  If the function $f(E)$ (or $g(E)$) is extremely peaked around some value $E_0 \ge m$ , then (8) could be written approximately as this:
\begin{equation}\tag{9}
p \approx \frac{1 - \mathcal{Q}^2}{3} \, \rho,
\end{equation}
where $\mathcal{Q} = m / E_0 \le 1$.  Asking $p = -\, \rho$ imposes $\mathcal{Q} = 2$, which is impossible with free (i.e non-interacting) particles.

---

**Remark 2:** Formally, the trace of the energy-momentum of radiation must cancels : $\eta^{ab} \, T_{ab} = \rho − 3p = 0$, which the expression $T_{ab}^{\text{vac}} = \rho \, \eta_{ab}$ doesn't satisfy ($\eta^{ab} T_{ab}^{\text{vac}} = 4 \rho$). However, in the case of the Lorentz invariant spectrum, the full energy density and pressure are infinite! Thus the energy-momentum trace cannot be defined: $\infty - \infty$ is ill-defined. We cannot conclude that the *infinite* radiation energy-momentum tensor isn't Lorentz-invariant. This tensor cannot even be found from an action!  So it cannot be included in Einstein's equation from a variation of the full action. This seems to suggest that the (Lorentz-invariant) zero-point of radiation cannot gravitate, and shouldn't be included into Einstein's equation! There's a kind of exit door here!

Comment: Doesn't your remark 2 imply that what you want is impossible? The requirements $T_{ab} \propto \eta_{ab}$ and $T^a{}_a = 0$ are in direct contradiction, unless the components of $T_{ab}$ are infinite or zero, which does not seem to me like a satisfactory solution.

Comment: @Javier, the infinities just open a door for something non-trivial.  There's no contradiction, since the trace of the EM tensor is $\infty - \infty$, which may be $0$, $\infty$ or even a *finite unknown number*.  The trace of the infinite EM tensor cannot be determined.  In fact the whole EM tensor itself cannot be defined if its components are infinite.  $T_{ab}$ just can't make any sense at all.  However, I believe there's a way to extract a finite part from it, and that one is of the form $T_{ab}^{\text{vac}} = \rho' \, \eta_{ab}$, with $\rho'$ a finite (unknown) density.